# query regarding TFS workitem

Tags: tfs

I want to know how I can update the field of my bug workitem. Suppose I need to change title of my bug workitem and after doing that I should get one pop up message box that my title field has changed without using email alerts? This is the query to select the workitem of a particular team project:

```
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection
       (new Uri("server url"));

var service = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

var qText = String.Format(@"SELECT [System.WorkItemType], 
          [System.Title], [System.Description], [System.Reason] 
              FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = {0}", "'Demo1'");
```

I want to know the update query for changing the particular field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
Dim workItemStore as WorkItemStore = tfs.GetService(Of WorkItemStore)()
Dim wi as WorkItem = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(workItemNumber)
wi.Fields("System.Title").Value = "Foo Title"
wi.Save()
```

Comment: Hi i want to know that how i can subscribe to workitem changed event using ISubscriber interface? i have gone through this link but i didn't get it where i have to write this code..http://nakedalm.com/team-foundation-server-2010-event-handling-with-subscribers/

Comment: If you're using TFS2010 and install the PowerTools 2010 then you get the Alerts Explorer which allows you to get notification emails when a work item has changed. I haven't subscribed to a workitem changed event using ISubscribe, sorry.

Comment: ya through that i am able to do..but i wanted to know using ISubscriber.. thank you ..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think WIQL supports dml commands. You are probably going to have to use the object model to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130323.aspx